# Feed is buggy when there's no activity on Android app?

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I have subscribed to many sites, but have no feed. I checked online, and I gathered this is not how it should normally look.

[image: Hot-questions feed works, but nothing else]

<sup>Buggy layout with empty feed</sup>

[image: So, it just showed something new.Am I doing something wrong? I just joined the site btw.]

<sup>Fixed after having activity (e.g. reputation change, badge, etc)</sup>

- Phone: HTC Desire 526G+
- Android: 4.4.2
- SE app: 1.0.77

Comment: Yeah, this is a known issue when the feed is empty: [Feed layout “corrupted” on Nexus 6 running Android M Preview 3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264531/feed-layout-corrupted-on-nexus-6-running-android-m-preview-3) (it was closed due to uncertainty of using developer preview ROM). Meanwhile, could you provide the device model, Android version and SE app version (possibly, the latest version, v1.0.77?)

Comment: Phone: HTC Desire 526GPLUS

Android: 4.4.2

Comment: Yes, it has to be the latest version. I downloaded it an hour ago. Will re-downloading the app help?

Comment: Not really. It's a bug of the app, not your account. You can just ignore it and move on now.

Comment: Link to related discussion on chatroom by Kasra (SE Dev): http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4564177#4564177