# The SE Android app has not been working for half a year

Tags: support, android-app

The Stack Exchange Android app hasn't been working for me for half a year. I only still have it for the notifications.

Even after reinstalling, notifications are the only feature that works. When I start the app, it only loads for some time and then shows a loading error. No home page, no notification drawer.

I also see that it's last been updated in 2017. Have they been working on a PWA the last two years or what?

I'm using an HTC one M9 with Android 7.1.

Comment: There's no more development done for the App.

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm typing this comment from it right now. It might help if you mention your device and Android version.

Comment: Added info. I don't remember doing any updates, OS or app, when it stopped working.

Comment: I'm running Android 10 on a Pixel 3a XL and it works absolutely fine for me.

Comment: @Shadow how on Earth is this a duplicate?

Comment: @Stormblessed because the app development is frozen. This answers the question "why the app doesn't work for half a year" which is asked here.

Comment: I'm not an SE dev, but I'll try my best as an avid SE Android app user to debug this: could you please post the screenshot when the loading error happens (no home page, no notification drawer)? Past experiences hinted on [a new user with clean-slate activity history & inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273944), but that certainly doesn't apply on here since you already got some comments. Otherwise, I noticed you're an Android developer, so could you check the logcat when this happens?