# Can SE add Progressive Web App (PWA) support?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

With app development frozen, there have slowly been issues popping up about their continued use (e.g. [The SE Android app has not been working for half a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333667/624390), and [Stack Overflow app not loading content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380819/165713)). I was wondering if there's been consideration in putting efforts in [Progressive Web App (PWA)](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps) support for the SE sites. Advantages:

- Separate "apps" for each community with no effort
- "App" support for SO Enterprise users
- Some level of offline support (whatever would make sense)

Comment: For the shake of mobile-web SE has the discontinued App , So I think implementing this would be of SE's interest now.

Comment: A lot of [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) posts, including the duplicate target *[How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)*, ought to be closed and/or changed.

Comment: Where is the MSE post about the final shutdown? 2022? Probably *[Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/)* (2022-10-19).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yes, this is the official shutdown of the apps.